# Why all vendor folder go to app/code?

Tags: magento2, vendor

After setup new magento site, i've met some weird situation.
All my vendor folders go to app/code instead. 
Also i can't find the Magento/Framework folder too.[image][image]

How to fix this situation, thanks.

Comment: Just to confirm you downloaded a zip of the site from the downloads section? Dont use git. Git is if you plan to submit pull requests and contribute to magento 2 repo.

Comment: Right, i do download from github.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please download from the downloads section of the website. Or you can use composer

```
composer create-project --prefer-source --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.3.2 ./
```

Where 2.3.2 is magento version.

Do not download from git

Git version is for magento core development if you plan to submit pull requests to the magento git repo